# Ruby pass object instance as parameter

Tags: php, ruby

In PHP I can do this within a class's method:

```
Condition::evaluate($this, $primaryCondition);
```

This allows me to pass the entire instance of the class to a different class via $this. How can I achieve the same in Ruby?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In ruby you have a `self` keyword. You can read about it [in this article](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_self.html), it explains how `self` behave in different contexts.

Comment: Okay, that's very different to how PHP uses self:: then. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Ruby of course.

Consider two classes:

```
class Foo
  def test
    puts 'We are in class: For'
  end
end

class Bar
  def initialize(your_object)
    @your_object = your_object
  end
  def test(i = nil)
    puts 'We are in class: Bar'
    if @your_object
      @your_object.test
    end
  end
end

foo = Foo.new
bar = Bar.new(foo)

bar.test

# We are in class: Bar
# We are in class: For
```

^^^^ You can see, you apply the method .test on the object stored in the foo variable.

The current object within a class definition can be addressed with the keyword "self".